# What is wrong with this predicate in Prolog?

Tags: if-statement, prolog, predicate

```
        findThree([H|T],_,3).    
        findThree([H|T], M, Z):-
            ( member(H,M)
              -> Z2 is Z + 1,
              select(H,M,C),
              findThree(T,C,Z2)
              ;select(H,M,C),
              findThree(T,C,Z)
            ).
```

So, what I'm trying to do is see if an element is in a specified list. If it is, I increment some variable, and stop if I found 3 of those elements. However, this does not seem to be working for me- is it a problem with my syntax? I'm trying to use an If-else construct in SWI-Prolog; could that be the issue?

Comment: I don't know much about prolog, but I do know that "incrementing a variable" is something you can't do.  Try a more declarative approach (I know that's not very helpful).

Answer (score 1):

`Z is Z + 1` will always fail for integers; that will compute the value of `Z + 1` and then try to unify it with `Z`.  Since `Z` will generally not have the same value as `Z + 1`, the `is` will fail.  You will need to create a new variable `Z2`, use `Z2 is Z + 1`, and then use `Z2` instead of `Z` in relevant places.

Taking your code and making fixes:

```
findThree(_,_,3).  % This should allow anything as the first element

findThree([H|T], M, Z) :-
  select(H, M, C), Z2 is Z + 1, findThree(T, C, Z2). % select includes member implicitly
findThree([_|T], M, Z) :-
  findThree(T, M, Z). % Allow this second case since it simplifies the code
```

Comment: Well, that works if I want to find one item, but for three items, it fails.

Comment: Normally, you don't write Prolog with if-then-else clauses, just backtracking.  You want to find `N` copies of a value `M`, right?  I couldn't quite tell from your question description.

Comment: Well, I want to find how many elements in a list A are in a list B. In this case, I'm trying to find out if there are 3 elements in A that are also in B.

Comment: @Waffles: Is that first statement in your program (`findThree([H|T],_,3).`) actually the query you are running?

Comment: @Waffles: See the new code I put in my answer; I think it fixes the issues and makes things simpler.